# Code-first models' relation definitions without virtual fields?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Is there any way to create `one-to-many` and `many-to-many` relationships without having to use `virtual` fields?  I am asking because I would be happy to reuse models created for the *code first* migration, but I do not know what to do with those `virtual` fields.  I just need a plain model without features like that.

P.S. I am using EF only for migration, so there is no issue with breaking the framework.

Comment: The `virtual` keyword is not necessary. They are only necessary if you want to achieve Lazy-Loading for navigation properties. If you are using EF only for migration, you could remove the `virtual` keyword without problems

Comment: Thank you, Fabio!  Add your answer, so I could accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The virtual keyword is not necessary. They are only necessary if you want to achieve Lazy-Loading for navigation properties. If you are using EF only for migration, you could remove the virtual keyword without problems.